# Filter fail to select data based on length in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
def match(i,arr=arr):
    tmp = filter(lambda x: len({*i} & {*x})==4,arr)
    for i in tmp:
        print(i)

t_arr = np.array([[10, 11 ,12 ,13 ,26 ,28],[10, 13 ,18 ,26 ,28, 30]])
match((10, 11, 12, 13),arr=t_arr)

result:
[10 11 12 13 26 28]
[10 13 18 26 28 30]
```

I want to select elements intersecting target one(10,11,12,13). The length of new intersected element should be 4. But my code fails to exclude `[10, 13 ,18 ,26 ,28, 30]` . And `len({*(10,11,12,13)}&{*[10, 13 ,18 ,26 ,28, 30]}` get 2, which seems strange.

Hope:

Solve problem and explain why my code fails.

Comment: @student It works but why generator failed.

Comment: May be that was not right approach, I think the answer below solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming one of your conflicting `i`s:

```
def match(i,arr=arr):
    tmp = filter(lambda x: len({*i} & {*x})==4,arr)
    for j in tmp:
        print(j)

t_arr = np.array([[10, 11 ,12 ,13 ,26 ,28],[10, 13 ,18 ,26 ,28, 30]])
match((10, 11, 12, 13),arr=t_arr)
```

Prints:

```
[10 11 12 13 26 28]
```

What went wrong in the original code?

Let's inspect:

```
>>> def match(i,arr=arr):
...     tmp = filter(lambda x: print('i:', i) or print('x:', x) or len({*i} & {*x})==4,arr)
...     for i in tmp:
...         print(i)
... 
>>> t_arr = np.array([[10, 11 ,12 ,13 ,26 ,28],[10, 13 ,18 ,26 ,28, 30]])
>>> match((10, 11, 12, 13),arr=t_arr)
i: (10, 11, 12, 13)
x: [10 11 12 13 26 28]
[10 11 12 13 26 28]
i: [10 11 12 13 26 28]
x: [10 13 18 26 28 30]
[10 13 18 26 28 30]
```

We can see that as we enter the loop because of the unfortunate name clash `i` in the lambda gets overwritten with the result of the previous iteration. By coincidence, the two rows of `arr_t` happen to have exactly four elements in common. So, at the last iteration the condition evaluates to `true` and the row does not get filtered out.